# Convert columns to rows in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, pivot, oracle9i

I need to write a query which takes rows and converts it into columns - here's my table:

```
Count    fname   lname   id
-----------------------------
1        abc     def    20
2        pqr            20      
3        abc     xyz    20  
4        xyz     xyz    20
1        abc     def    21
1        pqr     xyz    22
2        abc     abc    22
```

This is the output I'm trying to produce:

```
id  fname  lname  fname  lname  fname  lname  fname  lname
-------------------------------------------------------------
20  abc    def    pqr    NULL   abc    xyz    xyz    xyz
21  abc    def    NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   
22  abc    abc    NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL
```

The max value of count for each id is 4. I'm using Oracle 9i.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another one you might have some luck with.  I like @ThinkJet's but not sure how much decode costs (if more or less than this below.

```
SELECT
   T1.ID,
   T1.fname,
   T1.lname,
   T2.fname,
   T2.lname,
   T3.fname,
   T3.lname,
   T4.fname,
   T4.lname
FROM
      table T1
   LEFT JOIN
      table T2
   ON
         T1.ID = T2.ID
      AND T2.count = 2
   LEFT JOIN
      table T3
   ON
         T1.ID = T3.ID
      AND T3.count = 3
   LEFT JOIN
      table T4
   ON
         T1.ID = T4.ID
      AND T4.count = 4
WHERE
   T1.count = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you're after an Oracle 9i solution, but Oracle 11 introduces PIVOT, which allows you to do queries like:

```
select *
  from mb_test
 pivot ( max(fname ) as fname,
         max(lname) as lname
   for count in (1,2,3,4)
       )
order by id
;
```

which gives:

```
 ID  1_fname  1_lname  2_fname  2_lname  3_fname  3_lname  4_fname  4_lname
20  abc      def      pqr      null     abc      xyz      xyz      xyz
21  abc      def      null     null     null     null     null     null
22  pqr      xyz      abc      abc      null     null     null     null
```

Not quite what you were after, but extremely useful in many circumstances.... and almost worth the upgrade for PIVOT and UNPIVOT alone

**EDIT**

Modified to put fname and lname in separate columns

Comment: As in question, fname and lname must be a separate columns ...

Comment: Query and sample result duly modified

Answer (score 1):

Look at this example, same principle as in *@Mike M.* answer, but with true Oracle realization:

```
  create table my_table (
    id    number,
    fname varchar2(255),
    lname varchar2(255),
    cnt   number
  );

  insert into my_table(cnt, fname, lname, id) values(1,'abc','def',20);
  insert into my_table(cnt, fname, lname, id) values(2,'pqr',''   ,20);      
  insert into my_table(cnt, fname, lname, id) values(3,'abc','xyz',20);  
  insert into my_table(cnt, fname, lname, id) values(4,'xyz','xyz',20);
  insert into my_table(cnt, fname, lname, id) values(1,'abc','def',21);
  insert into my_table(cnt, fname, lname, id) values(1,'pqr','xyz',22);
  insert into my_table(cnt, fname, lname, id) values(2,'abc','abc',22);

  select 
    tbl.id,
    min(decode(tbl.cnt, 1 , fname, null)) fname_1,
    min(decode(tbl.cnt, 1 , lname, null)) lname_1,
    min(decode(tbl.cnt, 2 , fname, null)) fname_2,
    min(decode(tbl.cnt, 2 , lname, null)) lname_2,
    min(decode(tbl.cnt, 3 , fname, null)) fname_3,
    min(decode(tbl.cnt, 3 , lname, null)) lname_3,
    min(decode(tbl.cnt, 4 , fname, null)) fname_4,
    min(decode(tbl.cnt, 4 , lname, null)) lname_4
  from 
    my_table tbl
  group by 
    tbl.id 
  order by 
    tbl.id  
  ;
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/531936-convert-rows-into-columns

Comment: That's for SQL Server, not Oracle.